# using dplyr calculate row ratio

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df :

```
id  sample1_1   sample1_2   sample2_1   sample2_2   sample2_3   sample3_1   sample3_2
honda   4.464274    7.087345    2.659297    83.513596   49.299961   22.991566   19.679316
audi    1.454645    2.784645    2.692656    14.010951   7.674361    3.84253 3.795233
```

What I would like to do is to calculate

```
ratio =4.464274/(4.464274+1.454645)*100 for each sample between honda and audi.
```

for each row and bind it to new df

## desired output

```
id  sample1_1   sample1_2   sample2_1   sample2_2   sample2_3   sample3_1   sample3_2 ratio_sample1_1...sample3_1
    honda   4.464274    7.087345    2.659297    83.513596   49.299961   22.991566   19.679316
    audi    1.454645    2.784645    2.692656    14.010951   7.674361    3.84253 3.795233
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

## EDIT

standard deviation for sample replicates somthing like this but for each sample group

```
sample1_1_ratio     sample1_2_ratio     STD
75  71  sd(sample1_1_ratio,sample1_2_ratio) 
24  28  sd(sample1_1_ratio,sample1_2_ratio)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly different solution to get the same results, but organizing the data frame in a more manageable long format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather(sample, value, -id) %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  mutate(ratio = value / sum(value) * 100)
# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   sample [7]
       id    sample     value    ratio
   <fctr>     <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  honda sample1_1  4.464274 75.42381
 2   audi sample1_1  1.454645 24.57619
 3  honda sample1_2  7.087345 71.79247
 4   audi sample1_2  2.784645 28.20753
 5  honda sample2_1  2.659297 49.68835
 6   audi sample2_1  2.692656 50.31165
 7  honda sample2_2 83.513596 85.63341
 8   audi sample2_2 14.010951 14.36659
 9  honda sample2_3 49.299961 86.53014
10   audi sample2_3  7.674361 13.46986
11  honda sample3_1 22.991566 85.68042
12   audi sample3_1  3.842530 14.31958
13  honda sample3_2 19.679316 83.83256
14   audi sample3_2  3.795233 16.16744
```

If you want the standard deviation of the ratios, you can compute it as follows in the same pipe (mutates the value per row):

```
df %>% gather(sample, value, -id) %>% group_by(sample) %>% mutate(ratio = value / sum(value) * 100, sd_sample = sd(ratio))
```

If, you don't want values duplicated per row in group, you can run `summarise(sdev = sd(ratio))` in a separate pipe.

Comment: this works to, but my next goal is to calculate Standard deviation between sample1_1 and sample1_2 sample2_1...so on and soforth (ratios) not sure how i can do that in long format

Comment: Give a more specific case and I can give working code. You can do `filter`, `group_by`, or use plain vanilla `tapply`.

Comment: @i just checked the ratio is incorrect values from @Psidom are correct

Comment: It was missing `* 100`. :)

Comment: opps yes I changed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mutate_if` with `is.numeric` to create new columns for all existing numeric ones:

```
df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ratio = 100 * ./sum(.)))

#     id sample1_1 sample1_2 sample2_1 sample2_2 sample2_3 sample3_1 sample3_2 sample1_1_ratio sample1_2_ratio sample2_1_ratio sample2_2_ratio sample2_3_ratio sample3_1_ratio sample3_2_ratio
#1 honda  4.464274  7.087345  2.659297  83.51360 49.299961  22.99157 19.679316        75.42381        71.79247        49.68835        85.63341        86.53014        85.68042        83.83256
#2  audi  1.454645  2.784645  2.692656  14.01095  7.674361   3.84253  3.795233        24.57619        28.20753        50.31165        14.36659        13.46986        14.31958        16.16744
```

---

Or if the column names have start pattern for instance `sample`, you can also use `mutate_at`:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('sample')), funs(ratio = 100 * ./sum(.)))
```

Comment: I always think I know to use mutate, or gather until i realize i do not. works perfectly